# Chrome extension management API, access to 'installType'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, v8

By reading http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html I get the impression if I add to my permissions manifest thusly:

...
      "permissions": ["webRequest", "storage", "", "management"],
...

I should now be able to do something like this:

```
if(chrome.management.get('installType') == "development") {
    DEVELOPMENT = true;
}
```

but the error message I receive,

```
Error during management.get: Failed to find extension with id installType
```

leads me to think it REALLY wants an app id like:

```
chrome.runtime.id
```

but the signature is pretty clear that that is not the case:

```
Error: Invocation of form management.get(string, string) doesn't match definition management.get(string id, optional function callback)
```

So my underlying question is: How do I do this neatly such that I can set a flag if I am in an unpacked (and therefore, me developing) mode and do additional stuff that will not be required when it's in the extension store (in my case, change a web service endpoint)?

I couldn't find a bunch of examples with management.get, so I'm thinking the either the invocation of .get I have above is flawed, my permissions are not correct, and/or the error message on .get is cut and paste from getAll : )

Let me know how I can clarify this, I've been bashing my head for an hour and probably could use some leading questions ; )

Comment: There are a few ways to work around this, I do realize :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installType property is part of the ExtensionInfo structure, so when you get your extension using get() or getAll() this property should be set for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assist, here is a code snippet for those who many run across this: chrome.management.get(chrome.runtime.id, function(a){console.log(a);});